# Furnace motor not kicking on

Tags: furnace

I have a goodman furnace who's fan motor will keep running.  it's like it is trying to kick on, but it can't will run fast then slow down then fast again.
the only way it will kick on is to turn thermostat the whole way down and then 
up and it will run for a short while.

any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: What model is the furnace?

Comment: Sounds like you have a variable speed blower assembly.  This is a sophisticated system that provides heat benefits not available on lessor furnaces.  Please familiarize yourself with the design and dynamics of the system before you decide it is not doing what it should be doing.